# How can I monitor network traffic?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, network-traffic

I need to collect network traffic statistics so that if questions come up about how much traffic I'm using I have the answer independent of my ISP. I have a home network with about 10 devices including BluRay player for Netflix, and both Windows and Linux machines.

I've looked at DD-WRT, but I see that even buying a new router that will be supported is a problem since I might get the wrong version of the hardware. I have a DIR-655 and a DIR-501 - neither of which is supported. The DIR-655 only gives me "packets", not bytes transferred. I don't mind buying new hardware, but it's uncertain on which actual device I'll get in the box. DD-WRT looks like a bad solution unless someone knows of a place to get a router that is guaranteed to work.

Does someone know of an Arduino or other SBC solution? I have plenty of NAT routers already, so I just need traffic statistics for external traffic. The network is Gigabit Ethernet connected to high speed consumer internet service.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the version is critical for monitoring your overall bandwidth consumption. I believe it is one of the standard, earliest features provided by DD-WRT. From the GUI, go to Status -> WAN, bottom of the page, you get your daily usage.

As for installing DD-WRT, I share your concerns, but there is a solution. There is a number of router producers, Buffalo chief among them, that sell routers with DD-WRT already installed. No fear of bricking tour router, then.

Edit:

Just to give you an idea, this is the bottom of the Status -> Wan page of my Buffalo router, which, by the way, is exactly the same model you looked up, a Buffalo WZR-HP-AG300H:

[image]

As you can see, the traffic, monitored on a daily basis, is given in MBs, not packets.

Comment: The Buffalo idea sounds great. I looked up a Buffalo WZR-300HP rounter, and then found the manual here: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/438040/Buffalo-Wzr-300hp.html But the problem is that I don't see Bytes transferred each way. I see packets, which is all I get with my current DIR-655. Do you know how to get Bytes transferred rather than just packets? Thanks.

Comment: @Windy Weather I updated my post, to show you that the Buffalo gives exactly what you want.